# understanding a proof of existence of a function on R

Tags: real-analysis

The following is a lemma in measure theory book I'm following. I have some problem to understand the statement, intuition (example of where the lemma might be useful) and also have problem to understand the proof with sth like a goemetric elaboration.

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a compact set on $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{O}$ an open set containing $\mathcal{S}$, and also let $f$  be a continuous function on $\mathcal{S}$. Then, there exists a continuous function $h$ on the real line such that $h = f$ on $\mathcal{S}$, h = 0 outside $\mathcal{O}$ and $\text{sup}|f(x)|=\text{sup}|h(x)|$.

$\textbf{question about the statement:}$ the function $h$ is not defined on the set $\mathcal{O}\setminus\mathcal{S}$? this does not make sense as then it would not be continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

$h(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x) & \text{if} \  x\in \mathcal{S}\\ 
 0 \ & \ \text{if} \ x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathcal{O}
\end{matrix}\right.$

proof:
It suffices to consider the case where $\mathcal{O}$ is bounded. The set $\mathcal{O}\setminus \mathcal{S}$ is a finite or countable union of pairwise disjoint open intervals. Set $h = 0$ outside $\mathcal{O}$, $h = f$ on $\mathcal{S}$, and on every interval $(a, b)$ constituting $\mathcal{O}$ we define $h$ using linear interpolation of the values at the endpoints of this interval: $h(ta+(1−t)b) = th(a)+(1−t)h(b)$. The obtained function has the required properties.

Comment: According to the statement of the question, the function $h$ is defined on the entire real line. They just did not explicitly tell you the definition on $\mathcal O\setminus \mathcal S$ in the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a diagram of the construction I just sketched. There is a typo in their description $-$ you need to use the intervals $(a,b)$ that constitute $\mathcal O \setminus \mathcal S$. You're given $f$, $\color{orange} {\mathcal{S}}$ and $\color{green}{\mathcal{O}.}$ The question tells you to construct $\color{pink}{\mathcal{O}\setminus \mathcal S}$, and then use linear interpolation to define $\color{blue} h$ on the rest of $\color{green}{\mathcal O}$.

[image]

Comment: (I'm currently in a situation where my internet allows me to upload the picture but not view it...so I'll take the upvote as evidence that the picture is visible and error free)